# How to filter json data and display it on html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, magento

```
var filtered_value = $(this).attr("filterset");
    var filter_attribute = $(this).parent().parent().attr('data-facet');
    var count = 0;
    var filtered_json = [];
    $.getJSON('<?php echo $jsonFileUrl;?>', function (json) {
        for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
            if(json[i][filter_attribute] == filtered_value){
                count++;
                filtered_json.push(json[i]);
            }
        }
        //console.log(filtered_json);
        var filterList = $.parseJSON(filtered_json);
        console.log(filterList);return false;
        var html = '';
        for (x in filterList) {
            html += '<li>' + filterList[x].name
        }
    });
```

I have this code in my product listing page. And I am getting products from json file. Now I want to filter this products based on size, color,price.
How can I use filtered json data for building li ?
I am getting null value in console?:(

Comment: Can you give us your HTML as well? So we can see how the structure of the products look like

Comment: So is json an array of products? If so you can just got for Array.filter() function. This will return an array of products which pass the check. Then you just simply build your html as you started filling it with product properties from filtered array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work :

Javascript version  --

```
function tree(data) {    
    if (typeof(data) == 'object') {
        document.write('<ul>');
        for (var i in data) {
            document.write('<li>' + i);
            tree(data[i]);            
        }
        document.write('</ul>');
    } else {
        document.write(' => ' + data);
    }
}
```

jQuery version --

```
function tree(data) {    
    if (typeof(data) == 'object') {        
        var ul = $('<ul>');
        for (var i in data) {            
            ul.append($('<li>').text(i).append(tree(data[i])));         
        }        
        return ul;
    } else {       
        var textNode = document.createTextNode(' => ' + data);
        return textNode;
    }
}

$(document.body).append(tree(data));
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
// external js: isotope.pkgd.js

// init Isotope
var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
  itemSelector: '.element-item',
  layoutMode: 'fitRows',
  getSortData: {
    name: '.name',
    symbol: '.symbol',
    number: '.number parseInt',
    category: '[data-category]',
    weight: function( itemElem ) {
      var weight = $( itemElem ).find('.weight').text();
      return parseFloat( weight.replace( /[\(\)]/g, '') );
    }
  }
});

// filter functions
var filterFns = {
  // show if number is greater than 50
  numberGreaterThan50: function() {
    var number = $(this).find('.number').text();
    return parseInt( number, 10 ) > 50;
  },
  // show if name ends with -ium
  ium: function() {
    var name = $(this).find('.name').text();
    return name.match( /ium$/ );
  }
};

// bind filter button click
$('#filters').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
  var filterValue = $( this ).attr('data-filter');
  // use filterFn if matches value
  filterValue = filterFns[ filterValue ] || filterValue;
  $grid.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
});

// bind sort button click
$('#sorts').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
  var sortByValue = $(this).attr('data-sort-by');
  $grid.isotope({ sortBy: sortByValue });
});

// change is-checked class on buttons
$('.button-group').each( function( i, buttonGroup ) {
  var $buttonGroup = $( buttonGroup );
  $buttonGroup.on( 'click', 'button', function() {
    $buttonGroup.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
    $( this ).addClass('is-checked');
  });
});
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}



.button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.5em 1.0em;
  background: #EEE;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background-image: linear-gradient( to bottom, hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0), hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.2) );
  color: #222;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #8CF;
  text-shadow: 0 1px hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.5);
  color: #222;
}

.button:active,
.button.is-checked {
  background-color: #28F;
}

.button.is-checked {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.8);
}

.button:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 10px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.8);
}

/* ---- button-group ---- */

.button-group {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.button-group:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.button-group .button {
  float: left;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 1px;
}

.button-group .button:first-child { border-radius: 0.5em 0 0 0.5em; }
.button-group .button:last-child { border-radius: 0 0.5em 0.5em 0; }

/* ---- isotope ---- */

.grid {
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

/* clear fix */
.grid:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

/* ---- .element-item ---- */

.element-item {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #888;
  color: #262524;
}

.element-item > * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.element-item .name {
  position: absolute;

  left: 10px;
  top: 60px;
  text-transform: none;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.element-item .symbol {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 0px;
  font-size: 42px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}

.element-item .number {
  position: absolute;
  right: 8px;
  top: 5px;
}

.element-item .weight {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 76px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.element-item.alkali          { background: #F00; background: hsl(   0, 100%, 50%); }
.element-item.alkaline-earth  { background: #F80; background: hsl(  36, 100%, 50%); }
.element-item.lanthanoid      { background: #FF0; background: hsl(  72, 100%, 50%); }
.element-item.actinoid        { background: #0F0; background: hsl( 108, 100%, 50%); }
.element-item.transition      { background: #0F8; background: hsl( 144, 100%, 50%); }
.element-item.post-transition { background: #0FF; background: hsl( 180, 100%, 50%); }
.element-item.metalloid       { background: #08F; background: hsl( 216, 100%, 50%); }
.element-item.diatomic        { background: #00F; background: hsl( 252, 100%, 50%); }
.element-item.halogen         { background: #F0F; background: hsl( 288, 100%, 50%); }
.element-item.noble-gas       { background: #F08; background: hsl( 324, 100%, 50%); }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/isotope-layout@3.0.4/dist/isotope.pkgd.js"></script>
<h2>Filter</h2>
<div id="filters" class="button-group">  <button class="button is-checked" data-filter="*">show all</button>
  <button class="button" data-filter=".metal">metal</button>
  <button class="button" data-filter=".transition">transition</button>
  <button class="button" data-filter=".alkali, .alkaline-earth">alkali and alkaline-earth</button>
  <button class="button" data-filter=":not(.transition)">not transition</button>
  <button class="button" data-filter=".metal:not(.transition)">metal but not transition</button>
  <button class="button" data-filter="numberGreaterThan50">number > 50</button>
  <button class="button" data-filter="ium">name ends with &ndash;ium</button>
</div>

<h2>Sort</h2>
<div id="sorts" class="button-group">  <button class="button is-checked" data-sort-by="original-order">original order</button>
  <button class="button" data-sort-by="name">name</button>
  <button class="button" data-sort-by="symbol">symbol</button>
  <button class="button" data-sort-by="number">number</button>
  <button class="button" data-sort-by="weight">weight</button>
  <button class="button" data-sort-by="category">category</button>
</div>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="element-item transition metal " data-category="transition">
    <h3 class="name">Mercury</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Hg</p>
    <p class="number">80</p>
    <p class="weight">200.59</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item metalloid " data-category="metalloid">
    <h3 class="name">Tellurium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Te</p>
    <p class="number">52</p>
    <p class="weight">127.6</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item post-transition metal " data-category="post-transition">
    <h3 class="name">Bismuth</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Bi</p>
    <p class="number">83</p>
    <p class="weight">208.980</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item post-transition metal " data-category="post-transition">
    <h3 class="name">Lead</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Pb</p>
    <p class="number">82</p>
    <p class="weight">207.2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item transition metal " data-category="transition">
    <h3 class="name">Gold</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Au</p>
    <p class="number">79</p>
    <p class="weight">196.967</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item alkali metal " data-category="alkali">
    <h3 class="name">Potassium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">K</p>
    <p class="number">19</p>
    <p class="weight">39.0983</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item alkali metal " data-category="alkali">
    <h3 class="name">Sodium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Na</p>
    <p class="number">11</p>
    <p class="weight">22.99</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item transition metal " data-category="transition">
    <h3 class="name">Cadmium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Cd</p>
    <p class="number">48</p>
    <p class="weight">112.411</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item alkaline-earth metal " data-category="alkaline-earth">
    <h3 class="name">Calcium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Ca</p>
    <p class="number">20</p>
    <p class="weight">40.078</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item transition metal " data-category="transition">
    <h3 class="name">Rhenium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Re</p>
    <p class="number">75</p>
    <p class="weight">186.207</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item post-transition metal " data-category="post-transition">
    <h3 class="name">Thallium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Tl</p>
    <p class="number">81</p>
    <p class="weight">204.383</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item metalloid " data-category="metalloid">
    <h3 class="name">Antimony</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Sb</p>
    <p class="number">51</p>
    <p class="weight">121.76</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item transition metal " data-category="transition">
    <h3 class="name">Cobalt</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Co</p>
    <p class="number">27</p>
    <p class="weight">58.933</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item lanthanoid metal inner-transition " data-category="lanthanoid">
    <h3 class="name">Ytterbium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Yb</p>
    <p class="number">70</p>
    <p class="weight">173.054</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item noble-gas nonmetal " data-category="noble-gas">
    <h3 class="name">Argon</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Ar</p>
    <p class="number">18</p>
    <p class="weight">39.948</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item diatomic nonmetal " data-category="diatomic">
    <h3 class="name">Nitrogen</h3>
    <p class="symbol">N</p>
    <p class="number">7</p>
    <p class="weight">14.007</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item actinoid metal inner-transition " data-category="actinoid">
    <h3 class="name">Uranium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">U</p>
    <p class="number">92</p>
    <p class="weight">238.029</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item actinoid metal inner-transition " data-category="actinoid">
    <h3 class="name">Plutonium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Pu</p>
    <p class="number">94</p>
    <p class="weight">(244)</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a complete plugin. You can create elements based on Json. Hope to be useful. Good luck

Comment: Do you need further explanation in these cases?